# Sharepoint 2013 customizing List App style

Tags: list, custom-list

I'm new to Sharepoint and have been playing with SP Foundation 2013.  The division I work for has been keep track of projects via a shared Excel spreadsheet and it's been a nightmare.  So I'm looking into simply importing this spreadsheet into a SP List App.  I've done this and, functionally, it works great.  HOWEVER, appearance-wise I can't stand it.  The List App default appearance is ugly.

So, without going through the trouble of creating "master pages" and "composed looks", is there an alternate way to just modify the appearance of the List App itself?  Simple stuff like adjusting font and size, colorizing the column headers, etc. would be sufficient.

Comment: when come into UI,it's always about html and css, dive in the Dom, then try to overwrite default css, and use javascript if necessary.